# How to call function with two other functions output?

Tags: javascript, html

sorry for me newbie question, but I'm still fresh in JS.

I have two function in my JSP code. Function one, which returns me id of one component, and function two which gives me class of other component.

Then I have third function, which should use outputs of two above functions and do some things based on them.

I don't want to bring you a full code so this is example of the functions call in JSP:

```
<div class="dropdown-content"><a class="label" onclick="getClassName(this)" href="#">Open terminal</p></div>
<div class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown" onclick="getComponentId(this)" href="#">Open terminal</p></div>
```

And here is my JS snippet:

```
function getComponentId(el){
  var componentId = el.id;
  return componentId;
}

function getClassName(el){
  var className = el.className;
  return className;
}
```

Third function I want to run with the same onclick as the above functions. should I use this two function to call third function with a parameter componentId and className?

Comment: Use it where and to do what? Also, those two functions do nothing. Can you please give a better example?

Comment: Looks like you've spent too much time coding in Java - this sort of one-line function isn't at all common in JavaScript, and as Federico says, it looks like it does something, but actually doesn't have a return statement.

Comment: Okay, I edited the post. Sorry for lack of background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var ObjX={};
function getComponentId(el){
  ObjX["id"] = el.id;
}

function getClassName(el){
  ObjX["className"] = el.className;
}
function DoWhat(ob){
  console.log(ob);
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-content"><a class="label" onclick="getClassName(this)" href="#">Open terminal</p></div>
<div class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown" id="8888888" onclick="getComponentId(this)" href="#">Open terminal</p></div>

<div class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown" onclick="DoWhat(ObjX)" href="#">?_?</p></div>
```

Using Global Object save value is enough for what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the third function for the `onclick` and keep passing `this`

```
function thirdFunction(el) {
    var componentId = getComponentId(el);
    var className = getClassName(el);
    // do whatever
}
```

and in the html

```
<div class="dropdown-content"><a class="label" onclick="thirdFunction(this)" href="#">Open terminal</p></div>
<div class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown" onclick="thirdFunction(this)" href="#">Open terminal</p></div>
```

Now, in this case it is perfectly useless, as you can just inline the first row of each function directly inside `thirdFunction`.